# Expressjs. TypeError when call function in constructor from prototype function

Tags: node.js, express, router

I was trying to call a function in the constructor from prototype but keep getting the below error and I dont know whats wrong with my code.

```
TypeError: this.authorize is not a function
```

This is my code:
controller.js

```
var Controller = function() {
    this.authorize = function(req, res) {
        if (!req.user) {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    };
};
Controller.prototype.online = function(req, res) {
    this.authorize(req, res);
    res.render('./play/online');
};
var controller = new Controller();
module.exports = controller;
```

route.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var controller = require('../controller');

router.get('/online', controller.online);
module.exports = router;
```

If I put authorize function outside of Controller then I can call it but I don't want do that.
So what can I do?

**Update:**
This error occurs in Nodejs when I apply the request "/online", not in pure Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loosing context when passing `online` as a callback

```
router.get('/online', controller.online.bind(controller));
```

Or inside constructor

```
var Controller = function() {
    this.authorize = function(req) {
        console.log(req);
    };

    this.online = this.online.bind(this);
};
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked but only first case, thank you so much.

Comment: @carboncrystal Oh, right forgot the assignment for the second code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Set the authorize function on the prototype of Controller like you did with the online function.

**Edit:** I tested your code (not using Controller.prototype) and it works for me...

I can call authorize within the online function. Does the error occur when you call authorize from the online function or does it occur somewhere else? Are you sure there isn't a typo in your code?

Could you try to define your online function in the constructor as well?

```js
//Your initial version: works for me...

var Controller = function() {
    this.authorize = function(req) {
        console.log(req);
    };
};

Controller.prototype.online = function(text) {
    this.authorize(text);
};

var controller = new Controller();
controller.online("Some text");

//My prototype version: works as well...

var Controller2 = function() {};
Controller2.prototype.authorize = function(req) {
    console.log(req);
};

Controller2.prototype.online = function(text) {
    this.authorize(text);
};

var controller2 = new Controller2();
controller2.online("Some text2");
```

Comment: I edited the answer. It worked for me and I don't see an error in your code. Maybe you have more details?

Comment: Thank your reply. This error occurs in Nodejs when I apply the request "/online", not in pure Javascript

Comment: Nodejs is pure Javascript. It follows the ES6 guidelines. According to those, this should work... Have you tried putting the online function into the constructor as well? Can you call authorize from the controller directly or from another route?

Comment: Yes, Node built on V8 JS engine, but we're using Node and it's features, not only JS. ex: module.exports. The problem here is we don't completely understand all that features.